# How to add a frame number to Metropolis section and subsection frames?

Tags: beamer, numbering, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to add a frame number in the same format (fraction) to the section and subsection pages in my presentation. I'm using the Metropolis theme. I just don't really know how to go about it.

For example, this is how the title frame looks like:
[image: title frame with numbering]

and this is how the section frame looks like:
[image: section frame without numbering]

What I'm trying to achieve is the fraction 2/58 at the bottom right of the section page (it should be 58 instead of 57 because I want the section and subsection frames to be counted).

This is the beginning of my file:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\usetheme[block=fill,numbering=fraction,subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}

\title{Foundations of Software Engineering}
\subtitle{No Silver Bullet}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{No Silver Bullet -- Essence and Accident of Software Engineering}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just put the section command inside a frame.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it now, but then I'm getting an error for the subsection: `There's no line here to end. \subsection{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `\metropolis@enablesectionpage` (or `\moloch@enablesectionpage` if you use `moloch` the more modern fork of `metropolis`) to remove the `plain` option (I'd also remove the `noframenumbering` option, otherwise the result will look really strange)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar]{moloch}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title{Foundations of Software Engineering}
\subtitle{No Silver Bullet}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\moloch@enablesectionpage}{
  \AtBeginSection{
    \ifbeamer@inframe
      \sectionpage
    \else
      \frame[c]{\sectionpage}
    \fi
  }
}
\moloch@enablesectionpage
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{No Silver Bullet -- Essence and Accident of Software Engineering}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```